# How to Multiple Insert Laravel if the Input Form is showed by For Looping

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

CAN YOU HELP ME? HERE MY PROBLEMS :_ LARAVEL

1. I have input form, so if i fill it with number "3", the other input form will be shown x3 (as much as we input it).
2. How to insert the x3 Form Input into database with only 1 button submit then it will create 3 rows in table database???

HERE MY **CODE** :

```
@for($jumlah = 0; $jumlah < $trip_pesan->jumlah; $jumlah++)

<div class="form-group">
 <select name="gender" style="margin-right: 20px; padding: 5px;">
  <option value="Mr.">Tn</option>
  <option value="Mrs.">Nn/ny</option>
 </select>

 <input type="text" name="nama" placeholder="Nama lengkap" style="margin-right: 20px; padding: 5px;">
 <input type="text" name="nik" placeholder="kewarnegaraan" style="margin-right: 20px; padding: 5px;">

 <input type="submit">
</div>
@endfor
```

Please anyone help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your form to send input values in array for X items.

```
<div class="steps">
    <div id="step-1">
        <h2>Pesan trip anda</h2>
        <div id="form-step-0" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
            <div class="form-group">
                ID Pesanan : <input name="id_pesans" value="{{ $trip_pesan->id }}" readonly style="border: none;">
                ID Trip : <input name="trip_id" value="{{ $trip_pesan->trip_id }}" readonly style="border: none;">
                Jumlah Peserta : <input name="jumlahpeserta" value="{{ $trip_pesan->jumlah }}" readonly style="border: none;">
                <input type="hidden" name="total_harga" value="{{ $trip_pesan->total_harga }}" style="border: none;">
            </div>

            @for($jumlah = 0; $jumlah < $trip_pesan->jumlah; $jumlah++)
            <div class="form-group">
                <select name="gender[]" style="margin-right: 20px; padding: 5px;">
                    <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
                    <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" name="nama[]" placeholder="Nama Peserta" style="margin-right: 20px; padding: 5px;">
                <input type="text" name="nik[]" placeholder="NIK" style="margin-right: 20px; padding: 5px;">
            </div>
            @endfor


            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="SUBMIT">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You will have one submit button to submit the whole form.

Now in controller do something like below

```
public function inputpeserta(Request $request, $id, $slug, $package_id){

    foreach($request->gender as $key => $value){
        auth()->user()->trip_transaksi()->create([
            'gender'=> $request->gender[$key],
            'nama'=> $request->nama[$key],
            'nik'=> $request->nik[$key],
            'total_harga'=> $request->total_harga,
            'trip_id'=> $request->trip_id
        ]);
    }

    //your other things to do
}
```

Comment: what is mean of :

"values outside of for loop" and "values inside of for loop"

Comment: this means values inside for loop needs to be used like `'nama' => $request->nama[$key]` as they are in an array. And other values you can get by simply `'prop2' => $request->prop2`

Comment: sir, its still not inserting multiple rows (it just insert 1 row). Can you solve it by my last Comment? i've added a View and Controller. Thanks sir!

Comment: you don't need to add `[]` to those input fields which are outside of for loop. Check out my updated code.